# Left side Scrollbar in css

Tags: css

I design a web page,here i need a left-side scrollbar

Comment: If you are designing a website for a right to left language, and you use appropriate markup then that should happen automatically. If you aren't, then you need to fix the design so the scroll bar is not on the **wrong** side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this for the main div container :

```
overflow:auto;
direction:ltr;
```

Comment: its also change the text .....i only want to put right side scroll baa